# requests library fails to POST properly but urllib succeeds [python]

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to POST a query to the RSCB PDB web services, as outlined [here](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/software/rest.do).

I set up the url, and query as XML:

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import requests

url = "http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/search"

queryText = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orgPdbQuery>
<version>B0907</version>
<queryType>org.pdb.query.simple.ExpTypeQuery</queryType>
<description>Experimental Method Search: Experimental Method=SOLID-STATE NMR</description>
<mvStructure.expMethod.value>SOLID-STATE NMR</mvStructure.expMethod.value>
</orgPdbQuery>
"""
```

I then define two possible ways of POSTing this data:

```
def query_old_fashioned(url, query_xml):
    req = urllib.Request(url, data=query_xml.encode())
    f = urllib.urlopen(req)
    result = f.read()
    return result.decode()


def query_with_requests(url, query_xml):
    response = requests.post(url, data=query_xml.encode())
    return response.text

# result = query_old_fashioned(url, queryText)
# result = query_with_requests(url, queryText)
```

With the first function, using good old fashioned urllib.request, I get the correct result - a list of 4 character strings.

With the second function, which as far as I can tell is doing *exactly* the same thing, I get a JSP error message HTML returned. This is that error message when displayed in a browser:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
    java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:221)
    org.rcsb.servlet.RestfulServiceServlet.doPost(RestfulServiceServlet.java:1371)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:86)
    org.pdb.util.web.OutOfServiceFilter.doFilter(OutOfServiceFilter.java:91)
    org.pdb.util.web.DOSFilter.doFilter(DOSFilter.java:158)
    org.pdb.util.web.AntiRobotFilter.doFilter(AntiRobotFilter.java:29)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.61 logs.
```

I know a little JSP, but I haven not been able to glean a reason for the POST's failure from this error message, nor is it clear to me why requests is failing but the standard library's urllib is succeeding. I've even tried going through the source code of the requests library on github trying to find exactly how requests creates its requests, but I was not successful in this endeavour.

This is using Python 3. I first encountered this problem using Ubuntu, and have since reproduced it on Windows 10.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this.

I inspected the HTTP requests being sent, and saw that requests was sending this:

```
POST /pdb/rest/search HTTP/1.1
Host: www.rcsb.org
User-Agent: python-requests/2.8.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 316
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orgPdbQuery>
<version>B0907</version>
<queryType>org.pdb.query.simple.ExpTypeQuery</queryType>
<description>Experimental Method Search: Experimental Method=SOLID-STATE NMR</de
scription>
<mvStructure.expMethod.value>SOLID-STATE NMR</mvStructure.expMethod.value>
</orgPdbQuery>
```

...and urllib was sending this...

```
POST /pdb/rest/search HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 316
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.4
Connection: close
Host: www.rcsb.org


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orgPdbQuery>
<version>B0907</version>
<queryType>org.pdb.query.simple.ExpTypeQuery</queryType>
<description>Experimental Method Search: Experimental Method=SOLID-STATE NMR</de
scription>
<mvStructure.expMethod.value>SOLID-STATE NMR</mvStructure.expMethod.value>
</orgPdbQuery>
```

There are a few headers different, and by playing around with them, I found that it was the Content-Type header which is needed in requests' request.

The following now works:

```
response = requests.post(
  url,
  data=query_xml.encode(),
  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
)
```

Thanks to [Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36767917/4499072) for running my original code and verifying that this was technically possible. I suspect he has a different version of requests than me.

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the wrong content-type to send there. The fact that the server accepts it is bizarre. You *should* be sending a content type of `application/xml` or `text/xml`.

Comment: I just tried both of those and they both fail - it doesn't return an error mesage it just redirects to the RSCB docs for the web services. You're right though and it is a little frustrating as they might change it one day and break everything.

Comment: Although bear in mind that I am technically sending raw bytes rather than xml text, as I encode it first.

Comment: I was just about to make effectively the exact same question. Thanks for the question and answer!.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu machine it works fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import urllib.request as urllib


def query_old_fashioned(url, query_xml):
    req = urllib.Request(url, data=query_xml.encode())
    f = urllib.urlopen(req)
    result = f.read()
    return result.decode()


def query_with_requests(url, query_xml):
    response = requests.post(url, data=query_xml.encode())
    return response.text


def test():
    url = "http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/search"

    query = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orgPdbQuery>
<version>B0907</version>
<queryType>org.pdb.query.simple.ExpTypeQuery</queryType>
<description>Experimental Method Search: Experimental Method=SOLID-STATE NMR</description>
<mvStructure.expMethod.value>SOLID-STATE NMR</mvStructure.expMethod.value>
</orgPdbQuery>"""

    print(query_old_fashioned(url, query))
    print(query_with_requests(url, query))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()

    print("done")
```

Both print out the same. What exact version of python are you using? I use Python 3.4.3 on a Ubuntu 14.03

Comment: That's maddening! I'm currently on Windows, running Python 3.5. My version of requests is 2.8.1. I'm currently installing WireShark so that I can look at the HTTP request that actually leaves my machine and see what the difference is.